# How to get Sharepoint 2010 Wiki Page layouts to show with Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, wiki

I am trying to use Powershell to run through a list of wiki pages that were originally on a seperate wiki site. I want to migrate these to a Sharepoint 2010 Wiki site. I have a Powershell script that goes through all the files, creates a wiki page for each, sets the Page Content to the body HTML of the old page, and updates the itemm, but for some reason none of the layout is shown. The page is just blank with no boxes shown in Edit mode or Sharepoint Designer. Here is my script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://dev-sharepoint1/sites/brandonwiki"); 
$OpenWeb = $SpSite.OpenWeb("/sites/brandonwiki"); 
$List = $OpenWeb.Lists["Pages"]; 
$rootFolder = $List.RootFolder
$OpenWeb.Dispose(); 
$SPSite.Dispose()
$files=get-childitem ./testEx -rec|where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)}
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $name=$file.Name.Substring(0, $file.Name.IndexOf(".htm"))
    $strDestURL="/sites/brandonwiki"
    $strDestURL+=$rootFolder
    $strDestURL+="/"
    $strDestURL+=$name;
    $strDestURL+=".aspx"
    $Page = $rootFolder.Files.Add($strDestUrl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
    $Item=$Page.Item
    $Item["Name"] = $name
    $cont = Get-Content ./testEx/$file
    $cont = $cont.ToString()
    $Item["Page Content"] = $cont
    $Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```

Here is what a good page looks like in edit mode that was added manually:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/695/goodpage.png/

And what the pages look like done through Powershell:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/badpage.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The script needs to create a Publishing Page instead of a List item. Then it will add the appropriate Wiki Page Layout and setup everything for you. Here is my new script that works for anyone that may also have this issue - Note it also replaces the doku links with Sharepoint ones - :

```
##################################################################################################################
#                                           Wiki Page Creater                                                    #
##################################################################################################################
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") #Setup Sharepoint Functions

#Commonly Used Variables To Set
$baseSite = "http://sharepointSite" #Main Sharepoint Site
$subSite = "/sites/subSite"         #Sharepoint Wiki sub-site
$pageFolder = "Pages"                   #Directory of Wiki Pages
$fileFolder = "Media"                   #Directory of Files

## Setup Basic sites and pages
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($baseSite+$subSite)                      #Sharepoint Site
$psite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($baseSite+$subSite)  #Publishing Site
$ctype = $psite.ContentTypes["Enterprise Wiki Page"]                                #Get Enterprise Wiki page content type
$layouts = $psite.GetPageLayouts($ctype, $true)                                     #Get Enterprise Wiki page layout
$layout = $layouts[0]                                                               #Choose first layout
$web = $site.OpenWeb();                                                             #Site.Rootweb   
$pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)     #Get the Publishing Web Page
$pages = $pweb.GetPublishingPages($pweb)                                            #Get collection of Pages from webpage

## Get files in exported folder and parse them
$files=get-childitem ./testEx -rec|where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)}               #Get all files recursively
foreach ($file in $files) {                                             #Foreach file in folder(s)
    $name=$file.Name.Substring(0, $file.Name.IndexOf(".htm"))           #Get file name, stipped of extension
    #Prep Destination url for new pages
    $strDestURL=$subSite+$pageFolder+"/"+$name+".aspx"
    #End Prep
    $page = $pages.Add($strDestURL, $layout)                            #Add a new page to the collection with Wiki layout
    $item = $page.ListItem                                              #Get list item of the page to access fields
    $item["Title"] = $name;                                             #Set Title to file name
    $cont = Get-Content ./testEx/$file                                  #Read contents of the file
    [string]$cont1 = ""                                                 #String to hold contents after parsing

    ###     HTML PARSING
    foreach($line in $cont){                                            #Get each line in the contents


        #############################################
        #   Replacing Doku URI with Sharepoint URI  #
        #############################################
        ## Matching for hyperlinks and img src
        $mat = $mod -match ".*href=`"/Media.*`""                        #Find href since href and img src have same URI Structure
        if($mat){                                                       #If a match is found
            foreach($i in $matches){                                    #Cycle through all matches
                [string]$j = $i[0]                                      #Set match to a string
                $j = $j.Substring($j.IndexOf($fileFolder))              #Shorten string for easier parsing
                $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf("amp;")+4)              #Remove end for easier parsing
                $mod = $mod.Replace($j, $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf("id="))+$j.Substring($j.IndexOf("&amp;")+5)) #Replace all occurances of original with two sections

            }
        }

        ## Matching for files and images
        $mat = $mod -match "`"/Media.*`""                               #Find all Media resources
        if($mat){                                                       #If match is found
            [string]$j = $matches[0]                                    #Set match to a string
            $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf("class"))                   #Shorten string for easier parsing
            $j = $j.Substring($j.IndexOf($fileFolder))                  #Sorten
            $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.LastIndexOf(":")+1)                 #Remove end for easier parsing
            $mod = $mod.Replace($j, $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf($fileFolder)+5)+$j.Substring($j.LastIndexOf(":")+1)) #Replace all occurances of original with two sections
        }
        $mod = $mod.Replace("/"+$fileFolder, $subSite+"/"+$fileFolder+"/")      #make sure URI contains base site


        ## Matching for links
        $mat = $mod -match "`"/Page.*`""                                #Find all Page files
        if($mat){                                                       #If match is found
            [string]$j = $matches[0]                                    #Set match to a string
            if($j -match "start"){                                      #If it is a start page, 
                $k = $j.Replace(":", "-")                               #replace : with a - instead of removing to keep track of all start pages
                $k = $k.Replace("/"+$pageFolder+"/", "/"+$pageFolder)   #Remove following / from Pages
                $mod = $mod.Replace($j, $k)                             #Replace old string with the remade one
            }
            else{                                                       #If it is not a start page
                $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf("class"))               #Stop the string at the end of the href so not to snag any other :
                $j = $j.Substring($j.IndexOf($pageFolder))              #Start at Pages in URI
                $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.LastIndexOf(":")+1)             #Now limit down to last :
                $mod = $mod.Replace($j, $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf($pageFolder)+5)+$j.Substring($j.LastIndexOf(":")+1)) #Replace all occurances of original with two sections
            }

            [string]$j = $mod                                           #Set the match to a new string
            $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.IndexOf("class"))                   #Stop at class to limit extra "
            $j = $j.Substring($j.IndexOf($pageFolder))                  #Start at Pages in URI
            $j = $j.Substring(0, $j.LastIndexOf("`""))                  #Grab ending "
            $rep = $j+".aspx"                                           #Add .aspx to the end of URI
            $mod = $mod.Replace($j, $rep)                               #Replaced old URI with new one
        }
        $mod = $mod.Replace("/"+$pageFolder, $subSite+"/"+$pageFolder+"/")      #Add base site to URI

        $cont1 += $mod                                                  #Add parsed line to the new HTML string
    }

    #####       END HTML PARSING

    $item["Page Content"] = $cont1                                      #Set Wiki page's content to new HTML
    $item.Update()                                                      #Update the page to set the new fields
}

$site.Dispose()                                                         #Dispose of the open link to site
$web.Dispose()                                                          #Dispose of the open link to the webpage
```